# execute CONSTRUCT query one time with more than one result of WHERE clause

Tags: sparql

Given the below SPARQL query

```
CONSTRUCT {
sc_reserved:root sc_language:people [
rdf:type sc_language:borrower  ;
sc_language:works_for [
rdf:type sc_language:organization  ;
sc_language:has_organization_name [
sc_language:has_value ?01FWR5J95HZYQTGTKP88FXWBGB ]
]
 ;
sc_language:employed_as [
rdf:type sc_language:employment ]
 ;
sc_language:earns [
rdf:type sc_language:employment_income  ;
sc_language:_label "incomes"  ;
sc_language:has_income_year [
sc_language:has_value ?01FWR5J95HXQS44NEB89QXYPMP ]
 ;
sc_language:has_income_amount [
sc_language:has_value ?01FWR5J95H4WD8TAJEPGRBYXF3 ]

]
]

}
WHERE {
?01FWR5J95H8GFB7JKTZASYH2BG partner_language:reports/partner_language:employer ?01FWR5J95H1X58BRHAJ32Z2SWF .
?01FWR5J95H1X58BRHAJ32Z2SWF partner_language:name ?01FWR5J95HZYQTGTKP88FXWBGB .
?01FWR5J95H8GFB7JKTZASYH2BG partner_language:reports/partner_language:employee ?x . 
 
 ?x partner_language:earnings ?01FWR5J95HKQRQQG501RW7FSEN .
 ?01FWR5J95HKQRQQG501RW7FSEN partner_language:year ?01FWR5J95HXQS44NEB89QXYPMP .
 ?01FWR5J95HKQRQQG501RW7FSEN partner_language:total ?01FWR5J95H4WD8TAJEPGRBYXF3 .
  
 }
```

I receive

```
sc_reserved:root ns1:people [ a ns1:borrower ;
            ns1:earns [ a ns1:employment_income ;
                    ns1:_label "incomes" ;
                    ns1:has_income_amount [ ns1:has_value "2000" ] ;
                    ns1:has_income_year [ ns1:has_value "2021" ] ;

            ns1:employed_as [ a ns1:employment ] ;
            ns1:works_for [ a ns1:organization ;
                    ns1:has_organization_name [ ns1:has_value "SOME NAME" ] ] ],
        [ a ns1:borrower ;
            ns1:earns [ a ns1:employment_income ;
                    ns1:_label "incomes" ;
                    ns1:has_income_amount [ ns1:has_value "2000" ] ;
                    ns1:has_income_year [ ns1:has_value "2020" ] ;
            ns1:employed_as [ a ns1:employment ] ;
            ns1:works_for [ a ns1:organization ;
                    ns1:has_organization_name [ ns1:has_value "SOME NAME" ] ] ] .
```

which means the `WHERE` clause made the `CONSTRUCT` applied two times so got me two `sc_language:borrower` each of which has one value of the `sc_language:earns`

but in fact what I am looking for is one `sc_language:borrower` with two `sc_language:earns` as a result.

What should with my query to get this?

Comment: using input data

{
    "reports": [
        {
            "employee": {
                "salary": {
                    "pay_frequency": "annually"
                },
                "earnings": [
                    {
                        "year": "2020",
                        "total": "2000"
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2021",
                        "total": "2000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "employer": {
                "name": "SOME NAME"
            }
        }
    ]
}

Comment: then you have to generate a stable blank node to which all triples are attached

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I didn’t get it the stable blank node. I am quite new to sparql.

Comment: you have to reuse the same node for the borrower, this will automatically merge the facts. So what makes your borrower unique? What are the discriminating facts? Are you able to even generate a URI for the borrower? That is the only option, otherwise it obvious, for each possible "row" you'll get a separate set of triples with a new blank node generated